# How to access private repositories on Github and Bitbucket without permission of admin

Tags: github, bitbucket

So, my question is:

How to access private repositories of Bitbucket/Github or any other online web-based version control repository hosting service.

Any feedback is most welcome.

Thanks
Steve Washer

Comment: Why "without permission of admin"? What makes you think this is possible? The _whole point_ of private repositories is to control access.

Comment: Yeah, this sounds an awful lot like 'how do I haxx0r teh repo'.

Answer (score 1):

I'll only speak for github as a daily github user. The only way to access them is either by being member of the repository or outside collaborator of the repository. Owner of the repo can add you to it in the repository Settings.

Another way is to ask any of the members to provide you the personal access token, which you could use to read the repository via the API. This is however, unsafe.

Yet another way is asking the repository owner or any repo user to add your public SSH key to his account so you may have repo access (clone, commit) without ability to view it on github.com

Summary: you always need to talk to the owner or any of the current repository members. Private repo will never be accessible otherwise.

Comment: It's the same story for Bitbucket, and most likely also for GitLab or any other hosting service.